# Recommended books on food photography?

Tags: books, food-photography

There are a few good novice [food photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food-photography) questions in this community, but my question is a bit more specific: do you guys have some recommended literature (either printed or digital) regarding this genre?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The book I would recommend: [Plate to Pixel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470932139).

Everything you need right there and it was written by a friend of mine.  It is by far the most complete and most comprehensive "how-to" book out there.  Better than any blog (my own included).

Answer (score 4):

Read [Kelly Cline's blog](http://nommynom.com/). She pretty much *owns* food photography in microstock. Ok, on iStockphoto. She defined the category and is (I believe) the one to watch. Many talk about food photography but are weak on one or the other. Kelly knows both food and photography and can put the two together.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try Penny De Los Santos' workshop in [creativeLIVE](http://www.creativelive.com/courses/food-photography-penny-de-los-santos), where she shares her food photo style and tips, and learn how a pro photog works together with a food stylist and a props stylist.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this blog: http://nicolesyblog.com/